# Moving \Users directory back to the C: drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts, users

I moved my `\Users\user` directory to a larger `D:` drive when I set my SSD to be the boot/`C:` drive, using a symbolic link.

Now I want to move it back to the `C:` drive, and a larger, better SSD.

I think this needs to be from a recovery disk command line, right?

1. Boot from recovery disk.
2. Copy `\Users\user` folder from `D:` to `C:`
   as `\Users\user_new`
3. Delete symbolic link
4. Rename `\Users\user_new`
   to `\Users\user`

Will that technique work?